# how to retrieve mongodb data from an array and put it into discord embed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to reference the number of cards a user has, with the specific code that is tagged to each card.  the code works - but on discord embed, it shows the qty of cards as `{ cards: [ { qty: 2 } ] }`, rather than the number itself. any idea how to only pick out the number? thanks.

see below for the code.

```
//find number of cards the user has
         const cardQty = await UserProfile.findOne({
            userId: interaction.user.id,
            "cards.code": code,
        }, { "cards.qty.$": 1, "_id": 0 });
        

         //push reply
         const embedDrop = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setTitle(`${interaction.user.tag}'s drop • \`${code}\` • ${cardQty}`)
                .setDescription(`__**idol name**__: ${idolname} \n__**group**__: ${group} \n__**era**__: ${era} \n__**rarity**__: ${rarity}`)
                .setImage(`${image}`)
                .setColor('#99caff')
                .setThumbnail(`${interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()}`)

         interaction.editReply({
            embeds: [embedDrop],
         });
```

i tried using aggregate and $project but it doesn't seem to work - or at least i don't think i did it right. other than that, will the above code (ie findOne) be useful in an inventory situation? i feel like it might be hard to pull qty & other information of multiple cards in the user's inventory..

Comment: You need to replace `cardQty` by `cardQty.cards[0].qty`